omac1_aes_128 code in python for MIC ( Message Integrity Check) calculation in WPA2 PSK key exchange
For WPA2 PSK client,  MIC calculation in 4-way handshake is calculated using hmac.new(kck, eapol_frame_zeroed_mic, sha1).digest()[:16]. I am looking for similar function for 802.11w client in python which uses omac1_aes_128 as per open source hostapd code in crypto/aes-omac1.c.
I tried to implement omac1_aes_128 using python with no luck.
Need omac1_aes_128 implementation in python . Attached is the c code snippet.
int wpa_eapol_key_mic(const u8 *key, size_t key_len, int akmp, int ver,
const u8 *buf, size_t len, u8 *mic)
{
u8 hash[SHA512_MAC_LEN];
if (key_len == 0) {
    printf("WPA: KCK not set - cannot calculate MIC");
    return -1;
}

switch (ver) {
case WPA_KEY_INFO_TYPE_HMAC_SHA1_AES:
    printf("WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1");
    if (hmac_sha1(key, key_len, buf, len, hash))
        return -1;
    os_memcpy(mic, hash, MD5_MAC_LEN);
    break;
case WPA_KEY_INFO_TYPE_AES_128_CMAC:
    printf("WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using AES-CMAC");
    return omac1_aes_128(key, buf, len, mic);
case WPA_KEY_INFO_TYPE_AKM_DEFINED:
    switch (akmp) {
    default:
        printf("WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC algorithm not known (AKM-defined - akmp=0x%x)",
               akmp);
        return -1;
    }
    break;
default:
    printf("WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC algorithm not known (ver=%d)",
           ver);
    return -1;
}

return 0;

}
